# Site Home Page Edit

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I did a few searches and couldn't find an answer (the one I want...). I'm new to SP and web design as a whole.

My process:
I made a document library and I upload folders with html, css, and js files and make a copy of the .hmtl files as .aspx and that's how I create pages.
[image]

I am not able to do this for the site's home page. In SP Designer, there is an option to "Edit site home page" but it doesn't let me open it up in advanced mode where I can edit freely.
[image]

I've looked in "All Files" and haven't been able to locate what I think would be the appropriate file.

Is it possible to edit this page/file the way I want in either SP Designer or via SP Online?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you tried opening the site with SPD and then browsing to your page to edit in advanced mode?

Comment: Yes. That's what the final image is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior , When you click on `Edit site Home Page` , Click on `Edit page layout` , it will open the page layout of Home Page at new SharePoit designer as shown below:

[image]

From the above ribbon > Select `Home`  > select open it as `advanced mode`

[image]

Now , you can freely Edit it.

Comment: Did all that and got that but I didn't think this was the home page. Clicking on edit page layout brings up "PageFromDocLayout.aspx" for me. If i choose Preview in browser it brings up https: //gottahidethispartofthelinkcauseinterwebz/masterpage/PageFromDocLayout.aspx

I'll try it and just save what's currently there just in case. Thank you.

Comment: the home page consists of master page and page layout, and when you try to edit it from SharePoint Designer you can edit its page layout, the main issue for you that you can't edit it in advanced mode , and this what I mentioned above , when you tried to edit it in browser it open your page layout of your Home page. Note : take a backup before you change anything.

Answer (score 0):

**You can locate the file using All Files Option. Mainly it will be under the root directory and then right click and say Edit in Advanced Mode**

[image]

Comment: Amal, I looked at that and that's what I thought it may be as well. If I open that .aspx file up in the browser it shows a blank page. I already have content on the page so it's easy to tell if it's the related file. 

The page i want to change has a url of: 
https://sharepoint.com/sites/servicing/
This file took me to:
https://sharepoint.com/sites/servicing/default.aspx

Is that still the right file? I'll try this. Thank you.